# How to show the two numbers are coprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I show that $7^{13}+6$ and $2^{1001}-1$ are coprime?

I think it is a very interesting question, definitely not trivial as it first looks.  I believe there is an elegant mathematical proof to show this (which I do not know).

So far I see two possible ideas to attack the problem. One is to compute the gcd of $7^{13}+6$ and $2^{1001}-1$, but I do not know how to proceed apart from brute-force calculation. The other idea is to assume some prime $p>3$ which divide $7^{13}+6$ and $2^{1001}-1$, but I do not know how to proceed as well.

S.Dolan seems to have ideas and promised to give a full account once the problem is reopened. I am looking forward to the solution.

Comment: There are really only two possible ways of attack. You could factor the first number into primes and verify that none divide the second by using modular arithmetic, or you could simply run the Euclidean Algorithm. You definitely won’t be able to do this without a computer, unless some incredible coincidence lies behind these numbers.

Comment: obviously a bit more clever approach will be highly appreciated. ;-)

Comment: Use the fact that the latter has specialized factors ? $2kp+1$ for $p=7,13,11$ for a lot of them ? doh 4 of them.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Did you mean to say $2^k-1$ are factors, for $k=7, 11, 13$?

Comment: as are their factors, like 23, and 89

Comment: @maomao Are you allowed to use a computer? Or is the solution supposed to be doable by hand (in a reasonable amount of time)?

Comment: No computer please. I believe these is an elegant mathematical proof to show this (which I do not know, of course).

Comment: You should really make an effort to describe why this problem is interesting to you and what efforts you've made to solve it already.  It may help people new to the problem to avoid false starts and it will comfort people who are likely to flag this problem for closure.

Comment: You keep saying you believe there is an elegant mathematical proof, but you don't produce the slightest bit of evidence in favor of this belief, maomao. What makes you so sure there's an elegant way to do this?

Comment: WHAT MAKES YOU SO SURE THERE'S AN ELEGANT WAY TO DO THIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime common factor.

With a pocket calculator one can obtain the following.
$7^{13}+6=7(7^{12}-1)+13=13\left (7\frac{7^{12}-1}{13}+1\right)=13\times7453000801=13\times 61\times122180341$. The fact that the number $122180341$ is prime can be used to give a simple proof that there is no prime $p$. However, the issue is whether one can obtain this result without using a computer.

Let $g$ be the g.c.d. of $1001$ and $p-1$ and use Fermat's little theorem. Then $p=2kg+1$ for some positive integer $k$ and $2^{g}-1\equiv 0\pmod p.$
Note that $g\in\{1,7,11,13,77,91,143,1001\}.$

Possible ways of dealing with these are illustrated below.

**If the g.c.d. is 7**

$2^7-1=127$ and then $p=127$ is not a factor of $122180341$. The cases $1,11,13$ are similarly impossible.

**If the g.c.d. is 1001**

Then $p=2002k+1$ and, since $122180341\equiv 283\pmod {2002},$ there is a positive integer $l$ such that $$122180341=(2002k+1)(2002l+283)$$ 
Then we have $$61029=2002kl+283k+l$$
$$\frac{61029}{kl}=2002+\frac{283}{l}+\frac{1}{k}.$$
Then $27\le kl\le 30$ and the equation has no solution.

> The cases $g\in\{77,91,143\}$ are (just about!) manageable by this method but considerably more involved. An efficient but not very elegant method which solves these cases on a pocket calculator is illustrated below for $g=77$.

$$\frac{2^{77}-1}{2^{11}-1}=1+(1+2^{33})(2^{11}+2^{22}+2^{33})$$
$$=1+37310723\times 41507074$$
(I split this product up manually)
$$\equiv 26295054\pmod {122180341}.$$
Then, applying the Euclidean algorithm, g.c.d.$(26295054,122180341)=1)$ and therefore this case is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

$1001_{10}=1111110011_2$
Using binary exponentiation with mod and the rough $7^{13}\approx 2^{39}$ we get to skip to (logically not procedurally):

$a\equiv 9280402083 \equiv 2^{62}\bmod 7^{13}+6;011_2$ (okay cheated, as I messed up $7^8$ in my head using squaring method)

45356481461 is the remainder you get. You can apply the Euclidean algorithm again to get further, but I don't see an elegant way to move forward. I know by code that Euclid in mod form, takes 20 of these steps(for comparison their quotient using the subtraction version is

221182691952130532066935055250908832617886676341552822346039990897755119819325824099992375017734893567674831385947256289516489621924468698949071545714324062428270221429374296636022647970573635460915504441091818523032104802418130309305908587040097523770571250940918456042863244423724928417330

making that version infeasible to say the least). Even shortening them by using base $b$ exponentiation ($b^d\cdot x^2$ on digit $d$), isn't really going to help.

Comment: Since $1001 = 7 \times 11 \times 13$, you know that $2^{7} - 1$, $2^{11} - 1$ and $2^{13} - 1$, for example, are factors of $2^{1001} - 1$.

Comment: Suppose the prime $p$ to be a common factor. $7^{13}+6=13+7(7^{12}-1)$ is divisible by $13$. With just a pocket calculator one can express the number as $13\times 61 \times 122180341$.  This is a prime factorisation but let's proceed as if we don't know this. The gcd of $1001$ and $p-1$ is one of 1,7,11,13,77,91,143 or 1001. All but 77,91 and 143 are easy to deal with. I think this problem is worth reopening!

Comment: S. Dolan. Thanks. I think it is a very interesting question, definitely not trivial as it first looks like;-)

Comment: Can you elaborate this: The gcd of 1001 and −1 is one of 1,7,11,13,77,91,143 or 1001. In particular, why p-1 here?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I know see my comment on the OP.  I'm guessing that would shave a few things off. They aren't the only factors though.

Comment: The $p-1$ result follows from Fermat's little theorem by considering the least power of $2$ congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. If the post is reopened I'll write out full details.